# Why am I getting NSUnknownKeyException in setValue:forUndefinedKey:?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am making a small iOS application that tracks the amount of time that I have clocked in at work. I am very new to Swift and Xcode, so this is being a challenge for me. Details: I am using Xcode 7, the target development is 8.3. I believe I am missing something small like a class file. 
The app crashes on start up.

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ButtonIn.'

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.



    }
    @IBOutlet weak var Lb1: UILabel!

    @IBAction func ButtonIn(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.Lb1.text = "Clocked In!"
    }

    @IBAction func ButtonOut(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.Lb1.text = "Clocked Out!"
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the xib associated with this view controller. Search in xCode for "ButtonIn". You should find it there.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you have something setup wrong in the storyboard.  Can you post screenshots of how you wired up the outlets and actions?

Comment: In addition, this is a very low quality question. The title is redundant. Please view SO guidelines otherwise you will not attract answers and your question will be down voted.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Everything seems to be okay with your class afaik (except for conventions like methods beginning with small letters), so the issue is probably lying somewhere else.

Comment: I added screenshots, I do apologize for the low quality question, I am new.

Answer (score 1):

This happens usually when the bind outlet is changed. Follow below mentioned steps:

- Go to .xib file or storyboard scene for the class having this issue.
- Select "File's Owner"
- Select "Show the Connection Inspector" on the right panel
- If you find any exclamation mark on ButtonIn connection then re-bind it.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I do not see any .xib files..

Comment: In your Xcode's project navigator you can see .xib file for ViewController class.

If not then you might be using storyboard. If so then select your view controller in storyboard and follow above steps.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I can not find where the "File Owner" is.

Comment: Its alright. In your case (first screenshot) "ViewController" scene is your file owner. Select that and check connection inspector.

Comment: I don't see any problems..

Comment: Yes there is a problem my friend. Your outlets are not bound properly. Thats what I was talking about. The '!' (exclamation) type of icon. I did some marking & text on the third screenshot which you had uploaded and re-uploaded it in my answer. Try to remove those 3 bindings and run the app first, you can see there will be no crash and then re-bind it.

Comment: Issues Solved! Thank you!!